# Everything rendered in black except sky background in cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering

So, my problem is that I want to render my first proper ~10 sec animation in cycles and it all comes out black, except the sky background. Now when I display everything as rendered in my standard 3D view it all looks like it is supposed to be. What could be my mistake? I googled my problem already and did not find a proper solution... http://www.pasteall.org/blend/39100

Comment: StackExchange sites work best if you follow a specific Q&A format, asking one specific question per post. "What is wrong with my .blend?" questions are more suitable for a forum setting, like on BlenderArtists.org. We appreciate you looking for solutions before asking here.

Comment: Welcome to Blender StackExchange! Please set the title to be something more relevant to the question. so that people can be clearer on what they are clicking on. Also, please post clear pictures of what the expected behaviour is and what the incorrect behaviour is (even if you just post a black picture).

Answer (score 2):

Welcome!
In future questions, please try to provide as much detail as possible, optimally with screenshots to explain the question or issue.

Specifically here, it appears you added an overriding faulty material (Material.002) that replaces all other materials in your scene.

To fix the issue, remove it by going to the Scene Tab in the Properties Window, scrolling down to the Layer property group, then clicking the delete ("X") button in the Material box.

[image]

Comment: Wow, thanks for the fast answer, you guys rock! I tried to solve this problem for 2 days and I missed my deadline, should have asked sooner... Also, I will apply all your tips when I'm gonna have my next question ;)